# Canvas Draw TBitmap Multiplas Imagens

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, drawing

Gostaria de capturar várias imagens e "juntar" todas elas em uma só sem ter que as salvar primeiro, eu capturo 6 imagens coloco uma por cima da outra de acordo com a posição na tela e salvo em uma única imagem, alguém teria alguma ideia?  Estou usando Delphi XE7

```
function Unir(G1, G2, G3: TGraphic): TBitmap;

begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  with Result do
  try
    Width := Screen.Width;
    Height := Screen.Height;
    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, G1);
    Canvas.Draw(80, 90, G2);
    Canvas.Draw(100, 150, G3);
  except
    FreeAndNil(Result);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Dessa forma consigo unir 3 imagens, mas não tenho uma quantidade fixa de imagens, porque elas são variáveis, então no caso o ideal seria usar um `array` de imagens. Estou tentando usar a função abaixo, porém dá erro ao chamá-las:

> Incompatible type Array and Dynamic Array

```
function UnirTudo(Imagens : array of TGraphic): TBitmap;
var
i : Integer;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  with Result do
  try
    Width := Screen.Width;
    Height := Screen.Height;
    for i := 0 to Length(Imagens) - 1 do begin
      Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Imagens[i]);
    end;
  except
    FreeAndNil(Result);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Você poderia dar mais detalhes, colocar o que já tentou, onde está tendo problema. Sendo mais específico aumenta as chances de obter uma resposta. Dê uma olhada no [tour] e talvez na [help] para obter algum auxílio de como aproveitar melhor o site.

Comment: Então, consegui juntar as imagens em uma só                                              function Unir(G1, G2, G3: TGraphic): TBitmap;

begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  with Result do
  try
    Width := Screen.Width;
    Height := Screen.Height;
    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, G1);
    Canvas.Draw(Image1.Left, Image1.Top, G2);
    Canvas.Draw(Image2.Left, Image2.Top, G3);
  except
    FreeAndNil(Result);
    raise;
  end;
end;

Comment: Porém agora queria fazer isso usando um array de images   function UnirTudo(Imagens : array of TGraphic): TBitmap;
var
i : Integer;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  with Result do
  try
    Width := Screen.Width;
    Height := Screen.Height;
    for i := 0 to Length(Imagens) - 1 do begin
      Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Imagens[i]);
    end;
  except
    FreeAndNil(Result);
    raise;
  end;
end;      não estou sabendo como chamar essa função, da a seguinte mensagem incompatibles types array and dynamic array

Comment: Melhor sempre colocar as informações na pergunta.